# Issue with python webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to gather weather data using this website:https://www.almanac.com/weather/history/zipcode/10001/

The scraping to work, but the code randomly corrupts and the table in the html seems to disappear. Because of this, when I use find, it returns None and there is no data. This happens at random dates, and when it happens, all data sets for each day that is scraped after are filled with nones.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

year = 2000

def seperate(string):
  string = str(string)
  temp = string.split(">")
  outlist = temp[1].split("<")
  if outlist[0] == "No data.":
    return "none"
  else:
    return float(outlist[0])

dict = {}
while year <= 2020:
  for i in range(12):
    url = "https://www.almanac.com/weather/history/zipcode/10001/" + str(year) +"-"+ str(i+1) + "-1"
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    temp = soup.find("tr", class_="weatherhistory_results_datavalue temp")
    prcp = soup.find("tr", class_="weatherhistory_results_datavalue prcp")
    visib = soup.find("tr", class_="weatherhistory_results_datavalue visib")
    wdsp = soup.find("tr", class_="weatherhistory_results_datavalue wdsp")
    data = [temp, prcp, visib, wdsp]
    nums = []
    for item in data:
      if (item.find("p", class_="nullvalue")) == None:
        nums.append(seperate(item.find("span", class_="value")))
      else:
        nums.append(None)
    dict[(year + float(i)/12.0)] = nums
    print(nums)
  year+=1

print(dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this error. The problem is that server is responding with [429 Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) after multiple sequential requests.

Try to handle this error using `response.status_code` and add some delays in the request loop to avoid this issue:

```py
while year <= 2020:
  for i in range(12):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
      # handle error
    # ...
    print(nums)
    # Wait some time before next request
    time.sleep(1)
  year+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making too many requests in a short period of time, so as Gregory mentioned, just put a little time delay in there.

So Gregory's solution is correct, so please accept his, however I'd like to further expand and offer an alternative. Pandas has a `.read_html()` function to parse `<table>` tags in html (in fact it uses BeautifulSoup under the hood). Consider using that here. It'll do the heavy work for you and you can just do datamanipulation on the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import calendar

year = 2000

result = pd.DataFrame()
while year <= 2020:
    for i in range(12):
        url = "https://www.almanac.com/weather/history/zipcode/10001/" + str(year) +"-"+ str(i+1) + "-1"
        print (url)
        time.sleep(1)


        df = pd.read_html(url)[1].T
        df.columns = df.iloc[0,:]
        df['Date'] = '%s %s' %(calendar.month_name[i+1], year)
        result = result.append(df.iloc[1,:], sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

    year+=1
result = result.drop(['Precipitation','Wind Speed and Gusts','Pressure and Dew Point'], axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
print (result.head(15).to_string())
              Date Maximum Sustained Wind Speed Maximum Temperature Maximum Wind Gust Mean Dew Point Mean Sea Level Pressure Mean Temperature Mean Wind Speed Minimum Temperature Snow DepthLast report for the day if reported more than once. Total PrecipitationRain and/or melted snow reported during the day. Visibility
0     January 2000                    12.77 MPH             50.0 °F        999.00 MPH        37.0 °F                30.22 IN          40.5 °F        5.87 MPH             34.0 °F                                           No data.                                                       0.00 IN                      4.8 MI
1    February 2000                    16.11 MPH             35.1 °F        999.00 MPH        19.2 °F                29.82 IN          30.4 °F       10.13 MPH             27.0 °F                                           No data.                                                       0.00 IN                      9.9 MI
2       March 2000                    13.81 MPH             50.0 °F        999.00 MPH        21.7 °F                30.04 IN          44.1 °F        6.21 MPH             37.9 °F                                           No data.                                                       0.00 IN                      9.9 MI
3       April 2000                    12.77 MPH             64.0 °F        999.00 MPH        28.0 °F                30.16 IN          50.6 °F        5.41 MPH             41.0 °F                                           No data.                                                       0.00 IN                      9.9 MI
4         May 2000                    11.62 MPH             60.1 °F        999.00 MPH        26.8 °F                30.06 IN          54.9 °F        5.75 MPH             48.9 °F                                           No data.                                                       0.00 IN                      9.9 MI
5        June 2000                     8.06 MPH             84.9 °F        999.00 MPH        58.0 °F                30.02 IN          68.7 °F        3.80 MPH             57.9 °F                                           No data.                                                       0.00 IN                      8.1 MI
6        July 2000                    11.62 MPH             82.0 °F        999.00 MPH        53.3 °F                30.00 IN          73.4 °F        6.90 MPH             64.0 °F                                           No data.                                                       0.00 IN                      9.9 MI
7      August 2000                    16.11 MPH             75.9 °F         25.32 MPH        67.1 °F                30.06 IN          68.8 °F        9.32 MPH             64.9 °F                                           No data.                                                       0.28 IN                      4.4 MI
8   September 2000                     9.21 MPH             82.9 °F        999.00 MPH        72.5 °F                30.11 IN          76.9 °F        4.26 MPH             72.0 °F                                           No data.                                                       0.01 IN                      9.9 MI
9     October 2000                     6.90 MPH             69.1 °F        999.00 MPH        53.6 °F                30.19 IN          59.8 °F        3.57 MPH             48.0 °F                                           No data.                                                       0.00 IN                      9.9 MI
10   November 2000                    14.96 MPH             57.9 °F         24.17 MPH        34.7 °F                30.06 IN          48.9 °F        7.60 MPH             41.0 °F                                           No data.                                                       0.00 IN                      9.9 MI
11   December 2000                    13.81 MPH             43.0 °F         23.02 MPH        20.2 °F                30.15 IN          37.0 °F        9.55 MPH             33.1 °F                                           No data.                                                       0.00 IN                      9.9 MI
12    January 2001                    19.45 MPH             32.0 °F         23.02 MPH        12.2 °F                30.05 IN          26.7 °F       13.46 MPH             23.0 °F                                           No data.                                                       0.00 IN                      9.9 MI
13   February 2001                    14.96 MPH             48.9 °F         21.86 MPH        29.3 °F                29.96 IN          42.3 °F        7.13 MPH             37.9 °F                                           No data.                                                       0.01 IN                      9.9 MI
14      March 2001                    12.77 MPH             37.0 °F         20.71 MPH        11.7 °F                29.85 IN          29.7 °F        7.02 MPH             24.1 °F                                           No data.
```